# Can I set command line executed games to open in a window instead of fullscreen?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, games, fullscreen

I really enjoy some of the free Linux games and just downloaded Cave Story, one of my all-time favorites.  However, I can only play the game in full screen, 800X600 Resolution.  I was wondering if I could run this program in a window instead of full screen.  Is there a command or Unity plugin to do this?  Also, would the same work to run SuperTux in a window as well?  I'm running 12.04 if that makes any difference.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to edit your title to be more specific to the games in question or edit your question to be more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured from within the game itself, usually from the Settings menu. For example, here's how to [set windowed mode for SuperTux](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Games/supertux):

> The in-game configuration can be done running the game, then choosing
>   the Options menu. There you can configure: Graphics Mode (OpenGL/SDL),
>   toggle fullscreen mode on/off, Enable or Disable Sound and Music, Show
>   FPS (Frames Per Second) and do a Keyboard Setup (changing what
>   keyboard keys do in the games' action).

Comment: Thanks so much!  I also found the one for Cave Story.  It came with a configuration program I had to run in Wine.

Answer (score 1):

For most games you can find a setting either in the in game menu or in a game specific configuration file, most often located in `~/gamename/` or `~/.config/gamename/`. For games where that's not the case there is no clean way to force it into a window, but in some cases one can hack something together. For SDL for example one can force the game into the desired mode by overriding the parameter it supplies to SDL. Some code to do it for SDL applications can be found at:

- https://github.com/Grumbel/fullscreen-tools/tree/master/sdl